# Combining shapefiles and exporting

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am new to QGIS and I need to know if if is possible to merge two shapefiles that do not have a common field and then export to Excel.

Example of shapefiles:

- Countries broken up in to Municipality sections (not on a suburb level)
- Company active client base by suburb

Answer (score 1):

Try **Vector|Data Management|Merge Shapefiles to one**. It will merge the files into one and combine the attribute tables as well as possible.

If that does not produce the result you are looking for, please clarify the question.